# Agrupar registro por nombre y mostrar fecha más reciente

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo esta consulta

```
SELECT 
        pp.COD_REG AS CODIGO,
        pp.FASE_ID,
        pp.ID AS PROCESO_ID,
        eprl.NOMBRE AS EQUIPO,
        prl.UBICACION,
        pc2.VALOR AS ULTIMA_REVISION,
        plcl.VALOR AS PERIODICIDAD,
        pc.VALOR AS PLAZO,
        aps.NOMBRE AS TIPO_OPERACION,
        p.NOMBRE AS RESPONSABLE,
        pc7.VALOR AS LABORATORIO,
        plcl3.VALOR AS RESULTADO
    FROM
        procesos_procesos pp
            INNER JOIN
        procesos_campos pc ON pp.ID = pc.PROCESO_ID
            INNER JOIN
        equipos_prl_ceq_prl_vw eprl ON eprl.ID = pc.VALOR AND pc.CAMPO_ID = 3032
            INNER JOIN
        equipos_prl prl ON prl.ID = pc.VALOR
            INNER JOIN
        procesos_campos pc2 ON pp.ID = pc2.PROCESO_ID
            AND pc2.CAMPO_ID = 3035
            INNER JOIN
        procesos_campos pc3 ON pp.ID = pc3.PROCESO_ID
            AND pc3.CAMPO_ID = 3039
            INNER JOIN
        procesos_campos pc4 ON pp.ID = pc4.PROCESO_ID
            AND pc4.CAMPO_ID = 3170
            INNER JOIN
        procesos_campos pc5 ON pp.ID = pc5.PROCESO_ID
            AND pc5.CAMPO_ID = 3033
            INNER JOIN
        procesos_campos pc6 ON pp.ID = pc6.PROCESO_ID
            AND pc6.CAMPO_ID = 3036
            INNER JOIN
        procesos_campos pc7 ON pp.ID = pc7.PROCESO_ID
            AND pc7.CAMPO_ID = 3040
            LEFT JOIN
        procesos_listado_campos_listas plcl ON plcl.ID = pc3.VALOR
            LEFT JOIN
        procesos_listado_campos_listas plcl3 ON plcl3.ID = pc6.VALOR
            LEFT JOIN
        admin_procesos_select aps ON aps.ID = pc4.VALOR
            left JOIN
        personal p ON p.ID = pc5.VALOR
    WHERE
        pp.PROCESO_ID = 119
```

Que me da el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si os fijáis la fila 4 y 7 tienen mismo nombre de equipo (columna 4) y diferente fecha de revisión (columna 6).

Me gustaría agrupar para que solo se mostrara uno de los dos, el que tiene la fecha de revisión más reciente. Lo he intentado con `GROUP BY eprl.NOMBRE HAVING ULTIMA_REVISION = MAX(ULTIMA_REVISION)` pero me desaparecen los dos registros. He intentado de otras formas y nada.

Espero puedan ayudarme.
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma clásica de resolver esto es:

1. Crear una subconsulta agrupada por `id` del equipo y que retorne la fecha máxima
2. Incorporar esta subconsulta a la consulta principal mediante un `inner join` por equipo y fecha

La subconsulta con la `ULTIMA_REVISION` por equipo sería algo así:

```
SELECT eprl_b.id,
       MAX(pc2_b.VALOR) AS ULTIMA_REVISION
       FROM procesos_procesos pp_b
       INNER JOIN procesos_campos pc_b 
            ON pp_b.ID = pc_b.PROCESO_ID
       INNER JOIN equipos_prl_ceq_prl_vw eprl_b 
             ON eprl_b.ID = pc_b.VALOR 
             AND pc_b.CAMPO_ID = 3032
       INNER JOIN procesos_campos pc2_b 
            ON pp_b.ID = pc2_b.PROCESO_ID
            AND pc2_b.CAMPO_ID = 3035
       GROUP BY eprl_b.id
```

Luego hay que incorporar la misma a tu propia consulta, por ejemplo:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT eprl_b.id,
                   MAX(pc2_b.VALOR) AS ULTIMA_REVISION
                   FROM procesos_procesos pp_b
                   INNER JOIN procesos_campos pc_b 
                        ON pp_b.ID = pc_b.PROCESO_ID
                   INNER JOIN equipos_prl_ceq_prl_vw eprl_b 
                        ON eprl_b.ID = pc_b.VALOR 
                        AND pc_b.CAMPO_ID = 3032
                   INNER JOIN procesos_campos pc2_b 
                        ON pp_b.ID = pc2_b.PROCESO_ID
                        AND pc2_b.CAMPO_ID = 3035
                   GROUP BY eprl_b.id
            ) ULT
            ON ULT.id = eprl.id
            AND pc2.VALOR = ULTIMA_REVISION
```

Comentarios:

- Esto debería filtrar las filas con la última revisión
- Estamos asumiendo que `pc2.VALOR` es un columna de tipo fecha, si no lo es deberías convertirla tanto en el `MAX()` como en el `ON` sino tendrás problemas de orden si el formato no es del tipo ISO.
- Ten en cuenta que si un mismo equipo tuviera dos revisiones con la misma fecha, la consulta seguiría retornando dos filas, lo cual es razonable pero tal vez no es lo que quieras.
- Hay formas más cortas de resolver esto, por ejemplo mediante el uso del `ROW_NUMBER()` pero dependerá de la versión de Mysql que tengas.